# How to access instance of sub document in mongoose from parent instance?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
   var mongoose = require('mongoose');
   var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

   var ChildSchema = new Schema({
       name: String
   });

   ChildSchema.methods.getName = function () {
       return this.name;
   }

   var ParentSchema = new Schema({
       children: {
            type: [ChildSchema]
            default: []
       }
   });

   ParentSchema.methods.getChildName = function () {
       // How to facilitate ability to access instance of ChildSchema to call child.getName
   }
   var Parent = mongoose.model('Parent', ParentSchema);
```

In above code I wish to access `getName` method of `ChildSchema` in `ParentSchema`. How can it be done in mongoose?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to do with `subdocument index` as parameter as below.

```
ParentSchema.methods.getChildName = function (idx) {
   return this.children[idx].getName();
}

var p = new Parent({
    children: [{ name: 'Matt' }, { name: 'Sarah' }] 
});

console.log(p.getChildName(1));  // Sarah
```